# iOS Web notifications supported?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, web-push, chrome-gcm, safari-push-notifications

Does any browser in iOS support push notifications similar to Chrome on Android? Google seems to mention it in their GCM presentation video but I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently aren't any browsers on iOS that support the Web Push Notifications feature Chrome for desktop and Android do— or Service Workers, as you rightfully point out.

See the [implementation status of Service Workers](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/) in different browsers.

Apple has experimented with push notifications on Mac OS X, documentation for which [is available here](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the push notifications for web applications. Basically push messaging for web apps can be implemented through service workers and web app manifests.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client) only describe the implementation on chrome app but there is a reference on how you can implement it in web apps. You can check the full implementation [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/?hl=en)

Comment: You're right. But none of the browsers I checked support service workers on iOS. I already have a web app that works fine on desktop and android chrome, but it doesn't work on iOS. So I was wondering if there's something different that I have to do for iOS or if it's just not supported.

Answer (score 0):

iOS simply does not support Service Workers at this time. iOS browsers will not support Web Push Notifications. https://webkit.org/status/#specification-service-workers